# different app on Google Play Store look like same - React native

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo, google-play-services

I have posted 2 different app on google play store, one free few month ago and the other at 0,99$ few days ago because I need to monetize my project but Google says it's not possible to switch from a free to paid app.

So I have just change 2 lines in my app.json :

```json
"expo": {
    "name": "my-app pro",
    "android": {
        "package": "com.app.differentPackage",
     
      }
  }
}
```

The name : For making difference between the 2 different app.
The package : because google doesn't accept my second app if package name are same.

I did not touch the `slug` (Maybe i should?).

When I download my free app, and then, I download my pro app version, they look like same:
the free version has the pro features (but I have check, I'm not on the pro version)

Any ideas about why?